# Can I keep the Groovy power assert and still have a custom message printed?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, katalon, assert, groovy

I use **Katalon Studio** for my test automation. It comes with an in-built script editor (**Groovy**).

So, I can use Groovy's power assert that gives me a nice and detailed output message when the assert fails.

However, some other non-technical (or less-technical) staff would like to run automated tests themselves. And their problem is they are unable to correctly interpret the fail message.

I know I can use `assert expression1 : expression2` for printing the custom message, but I really prefer the power assert output.

Is there a way to have both custom message and power assert message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436597/can-i-keep-the-groovy-power-assert-and-still-have-a-custom-message-printed). In short:

It is possible to add the message as a String to an assertion:

```
assert "a custom message" && expression
```

> Since a non-empty String is truthy in Groovy, the assertion will only fail –and produce output– if the expression is falsey + you'll get power assertion output from it.